# Can I run multiple taskManager in one single pc?

Tags: apache-flink

**flink version**: 1.10 
**os**: centos 7 
**detail**:
I've started a standlone flink cluster in my server.Then I can see one taskManager in flink web-ui.
[image: taskManager]

**Question**: Is it reasonable to run another taskManger on this server?
Here's my step(For now, flink cluster has been started):
1. Im my server, go to flink's root directory.Then start another taskManger:

```
cd bin
./taskManager.sh start
```

2. For a while, There are two taskManager appear in my flink web-ui.

And if run multiple taskManager in one single server is accetpable. What should I take a notice when I'm doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing task manager (TM) has 4 slots and has 4 CPU cores available to it. Whether it's reasonable to run another TM depends on what resources the server has, and how resource intensive your workload is. If your server still has free cores and isn't busy doing other things besides running Flink, then sure, run another TM -- or make this one bigger.

What matters most is how many total task slots are being provided by the server. As a starting point, you might think in terms of one slot per CPU core. Whether those slots are all in on TM, or each in their own TM, or somewhere in between, is a secondary concern. (See [Is one TaskManager with three slots the same as three TaskManagers with one slot in Apache Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326839/is-one-taskmanager-with-three-slots-the-same-as-three-taskmanagers-with-one-slot) for discussion of that point.)

Comment: I've seen that post you mentioned.My server has 4 cpu cores,So I can only get 4 slots, 4 parallelism. Is that mean my flink program's ability of parallel processing is just 4, is it possible if I want more.

Comment: You can configure a server with 4 cores to have as many slots as you want. I've seen deployments using 3 cores per slot, and others with 10 slots per core. It all depends on the resource requirements of the jobs you will run on the cluster. One slot per core is just a reasonable default. You'll be able to tell if you've gone too far because the job(s) will experience backpressure, or they will run out of memory.

Comment: Then is multiple slots per CPU cores the same as one slots per CPU cores?eg: 4 CPU cores for 4 task slots or 16 task slots(4 slots per CPU cores).

Comment: My understanding is 16 slots for 4 CPU cores will split server memory in 16, and will get better in parallel processing.So if my server has enough memory, I can configure as many slots as I want to improve my program's ability of parallel processing.